# Network energy function matrix representation

Tags: matrices, network

The question seems very simple, however I`m trying to find the right [blas-function](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node145.html) which correctly describes the following expression:
$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}{w_{ij}x_ix_j}$

Is it `_ssymv` and `_sdsdot` combination?

Thanks for help!

Comment: could you elaborate a bit? the sum you are mentioning is looks like a matrix product (bilinear form)...with some sort of a weight matrix

Comment: w - weight matrix, x - is a vector of neurons states. So, we take two neurons - i and j (from vector x) and weight of connection between them. I would understand how represent the same expression, if it was simply w_ij * x - it`s a multiplication of A*x, where A-matrix and x-vector, but in this case it`s not simple A*x, it`s A * [differen elements of the same vector x].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the functions you're referencing to, but:

The term
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}{w_{ij}x_ix_j}
$$
is nothing more than the result of two matrix multiplications, you can also see this as an application of a [bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form), so in fact you have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}{w_{ij}x_ix_j}=x^t W x\in\mathbb R
$$
where $W=\begin{pmatrix}w_{11}&w_{12}&\ldots\\w_{21}&\ddots\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb R^{N\times N}$ and $x\in\mathbb R^N$. So it is somehow a weighted "scalar product", also the property of being a scalar product actually depends on the weight matrix $W$ (like being symmetric etc.).